# C++ clase shared_ptr fallo de segmentación

Tags: c++, punteros-inteligentes

Tengo un fallo de segmentación en mi programa de prueba,os dejo por aquí el main,es muy simple.
Debajo esta el archivo.hpp
Estoy trabajando en linux por si surge la duda.

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class AVLTNode
{
public:

    typedef std::shared_ptr< AVLTNode<T> > Ref;

    AVLTNode (T const& it=T(), AVLTNode<T>::Ref parent=nullptr, AVLTNode<T>::Ref left=nullptr, AVLTNode<T>::Ref right=nullptr):
        _item(it), parent_(parent), left_(left), right_(right), height_(0)
    {}

    void set_item(const T& new_it)
    {
        _item = new_it;
    }
protected:
    T _item;
    AVLTNode<T>::Ref parent_;
    AVLTNode<T>::Ref left_;
    AVLTNode<T>::Ref right_;
    int height_;
};

int main(){
  AVLTNode<int>::Ref nodo;

  nodo.get()->set_item(4);

  return 0;
}
```

Me esta dando el error de segmentación en esta línea.

nodo.get()->set_item(4);

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta pues estás en SO en español, de lo contrario es seguro termine cerrada

Comment: Gracias por la observación ya la he puesto en español.

Comment: Eres nuevo en el sitio y es tu primera pregunta; así que te la he arreglado. Para futuras cuestiones, por favor, proporciona un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es muy sencillo de reproducir; no tiene nada que ver con plantillas:

```
int main( ) {
  int *ptr = nullptr;

  *ptr = 4;

  return 0;
}
```

¿ Cómo ? ¿ Que no se parecen ? Claro que si:

Veamos en [su documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) algunos de los constructores que la clase `shared_ptr` proporciona:

> constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept; // (1)
>   constexpr shared_ptr( std::nullptr_t ) noexcept; // (2)
>   
>   1-2) Constructs a shared_ptr with no managed object, i.e. empty shared_ptr

Es decir, si no le indicas **que objeto tiene que manejar**, `shared_ptr` se inicializa como *vacío*: **equivale a un `nullptr`**.

Y acceder a un puntero *nulo* es un comportamiento indefinido ... que en la mayoría de sistemas modernos resulta en un *bonito* error de acceso a memoria.

¿ La solución ? Pues muy sencillo: proporciona un *objeto* que manejar:

```
int main( ) {
  AVLTNode< int >::Ref nodo{ new AVLTNode( ) };

  nodo.get( )->set_item( 4 );

  return 0;
}
```